# Why I have an alignment problem when displaying the ASCII characters in a loop?

Tags: c

I want to write a program which prints each letter with ASCII number. 
The program should print 8 letters with ASCII number in one verse so I decide to make a counter and in each loop it should increment this variable.

The problem is more visible on this screenshot:

[image: program output]

Why are spaces are not equal? 
I think that something is wrong with loop.

My code:

```
int main(void) {
    char ch;
    int flag = 0;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '#') {
        if (isalpha(ch)) {
            flag++;
            printf("%c : %d \t", ch, ch);
        }
        if ((flag % 8) == 0) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try printf("%c : %3d ", ch, ch);

Comment: well you use \t (tab) which almost always not do what you are expecting here: having the indent to be the same; use constant format length

Comment: related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3973/why-are-tab-characters-variable-width

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the loop. its causes for extra " "(space) before `\t`. replace your first printf function with this:

`printf("%c : %d\t", ch, ch);`.

The spaces will be equal.

Answer (score 0):

The loop is almost OK, you should more the test on `flag` inside the test on `isalpha(c)` otherwise you might print multiple newlines if the set of letters was not contiguous.

The alignment problem comes from the number of characters output before the TAB: `"%c : %d \t"` produces a single character for `%c`, 3 characters for `:`, up to 3 characters for `%d`, and another character for  : that's 8 characters for `c >= 100`. The TAB character expands to the number of spaces needed to reach a column multiple of 8. Hence 1 space for `c < 100` and 8 spaces for `c >= 100`.

You can fix this by removing the extra space before the `\t`.

Also note that you should read bytes from the input stream into an `int` variable and test for `EOF` too.

Here is a modified version:

```
int main(void) {
    int ch;
    int flag = 0;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && c != '#') {
        if (isalpha(ch)) {
            printf("%c : %d\t", ch, ch);
            flag++;
            if ((flag % 8) == 0)
                printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```